# How does the ${} in spring worked ,why it could take the environment value into spring context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a NutShell , i define a variables at my environment

`export host=localhost`

and  my jdbc url in spring is  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc://${host}://root...`.

after the config work done , the url in spring would be `spring.datasource.url=jdbc://localhost://root...`  ,so could someone explain what the effort that spring had done ? or which article should i take a look in spring ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html